# jquery mobile and Durandal

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, breeze, durandal

Please anyone suggest me, it's good idea to use Durandal and JuqueryMobile for mobile based application (Browser). I am planning to develop an application using Durandal, Jquerymobile, MVC4, KnockoutJs, and BreezeJs.

Thanks

Comment: Is it going to be hybrid app (accessible from marketplace) or mobile web app?

Comment: Are you making app only for modern devices? Or do you want to support older devices?

Comment: jqm has been designed as an "overall framework" => difficult to use within another framework. jqm performs a whole page compilation to enahnce all html, accordingly it pretends to handle itself all mobile page changes. Very difficult to match the jquery mobile page engine with the Durandall views engine so you will be forced to renounce to use jqm page engine. This in turn creates a lot of difficulties in initializing mobile widgets properly because everything has  been designed to live within a mobile page. This means problems of css and initialization for widgets used without a page context

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't recommend using jQuery mobile because it has a lot of overlapping features w/ durandal.  Unless you want to just use jQuery mobile for the controls.

I asked on the [google group forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/durandaljs/gtyh3Xoq_YQ) and [ratchet](http://maker.github.com/ratchet/) was suggested instead.

Not exactly the answer your looking for but.. it might be good to consider other options too.

Comment: Thanks Evan I saw it and seem good for current development. But I am not sure will it be good for future.

Answer (score 3):

Yes I believe this is a sound approach. We're using jquery UI (not the mobile version) with the durandal framework with success on a large web app.

If you include the jquery ui widget bindings by Steve Saunderson (https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/wiki/Bindings---jqueryui-widgets) you can achieve a fully declarative UI approach.

It will allow you to declare something like the jquery ui autocomplete control within the HTML like this:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="
            css: { 'song-valid': isValid, 'song-invalid': isInvalid },
            value: songSearchText, 
            valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', 
            attr: { placeholder: placeholderText },
            jqueryui: {
                widget: 'autocomplete',
                options: {
                    source: function(request, response) { return $data.songAutoCompleteSource(request, response); },
                    minLength: 2,
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $data.songSelected(ui.item.id, ui.item.value);
                        $parent.songSelected();
                    }
                }
            }" />
```

Simply include the jquery ui widget bindings found in this gist: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/wiki/Bindings---jqueryui-widgets

Make sure you include the above javascript after you have already loaded jquery and knockout.

Comment: Thanks Alex, But my concern is, we will able to get JqueryMobile look and feel on mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

I would say no. I made a simple PhoneGap app with 3 pages with JQuery Mobile. It looked good. I then tried to implement Durandal and it broke all my JQuery mobile styling. I came to the conclusion that the 2 do not play well together as Jquery Mobile tries to implement it's own page navigation model. I am now going to try Bootstrap instead or possibly handcode the css for the UI.

If anyone can prove otherwise, please let me know!

Comment: did you try to disable the ajax page changes within JQM?