# Bootstrap typeahead inside Durandal SPA application

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, durandal, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a SPA application using the default durandal package set-up. I am using Knockout, Jquery, Jquery ui, and trying to use the twitter bootstrap typeahead. I building on the default durandal pages using this html on my shell.html(navbar)

```
<form class="navbar-search pull-right">
    <input type="text" class="search-query" id="employeeSearch" placeholder="Search Employees" data-bind="typeahead: employees">
</form>
```

In order to use the typeahead as a custom knockout binding I am using the answers provided here [Creating a autocomplete field with Typeahead in the Durandal Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195200/creating-a-autocomplete-field-with-typeahead-in-the-durandal-framework/16355062#16355062)

I am creating my own datasource in my connected js file here

```
this.employees = function () {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax(app.url('/employees'),
    {
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (result) {
            self.employees = result;
        }
    });  
};

var shell = {
    router: router,
    employees: employees,
    activate: function () {
        return boot();
    }
};

return shell;
```

I am using Nancy on the backend to create a webservice so that is the reason for using jsonp as my dataType. I am able to get my results back fine, however when loading the page, i keep getting an error "Object [object Object] has no method 'typeahead'" in chrome debugger where the page never finishes loading.

Also, when I remove the knockout-bootstrap library, the page is able to load without any errors, but the search box is non functional. I have also made sure that I am including all my libraries in the right order, jQuery->jQueryUI->knockout->bootstrap->custom javascript. Most of all the examples I have seen work, but I cannot wrap my head around this problem!

Most of the examples I have seen use this content in their js

```
$('#employeeSearch').typeahead({
source: function (query, process) {

    return $.get(window.location.pathname +'?ajax=accounts&ajax_mode=search', { 'value': query }, function (data) {
        return process(data.result);
    });
},
minLength: 1,
items: 12
});  //A rough example
```

I have tried using this method but have not been able to within the SPA framework. Let me know any thoughts or is more code is needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do few checks:

1. Make sure you are calling/ referencing the bootstrap-typeahead.js
2. Make sure you have no more than one reference to bootstrap-typeahead.js
3. Because the modules are loaded as AMD via requirejs, make sure you have the following in the module you are making use of typeahead feature e.g.
   **require('scripts/bootstrap-typeahead.js')**

Comment: Does the original bootstrap.js conflict with the bootstrap-typeahead.js? I have already had some conflict problems with bootstrap.js and jqueryui.js creating some other jqueryui knockout bindingHandlers on the UI. Mainly rendering the controls correctly.